# Count together two objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I started learning c# recently. And now I have decided to create something similar to shopping cart in console. This is how far I have gotten for now. I was wondering what should I do next if I want to count the total price of the purchase. Thanks in advance !

```
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product1 = new Product();
            product1.Register();
            product1.output();

            Product product2 = new Product();
            product2.Register();
            product2.output();
        }
        class Product
        {
            public string name;
            public double price;
            public void Register()
            {
                Console.Write("What will you buy:");
                name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("How much it costs:");
                price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            public void output()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You have bought {name} , that costs {price} dollars");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a shopping cart.

```
  List<Product> shoppingCart = new List<Product>();

  shoppingCart.Add(product1);
  ...
  shoppingCart.Add(product2);
  ....
```

now you can do

```
  double total = 0;
  foreach(var product in shoppingCart){
      total += product.Price;
  }
```

BTW

I would not put the code to ask the user what to buy in the Product class. I would make it separate function. And output too. Imagine later you want to load the items out of a database, then you dont want to do console IO. Keep the storage details separate from the objects that really dont care how they came into being

Comment: @Steventheglide78, take this answer and followthrough with [reading up on C# `List` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0). With a particular need in mind, like a shopping cart, there will be "a-ha" moments as you realize solutions to various problems.

Comment: @radarbob - yup I could have gone on at length but thought just giving a prod in the right direction was best start.

Comment: "... gone at length".   That would muddy the answer.